# Help with avoiding CURSOR for Column Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, cursor, aggregate-functions

I have a bunch of records in a table variable like so:

```
Id     ProductId   Rank    RankCreated
1      123213      2       2011-05-02
2      123213      4       2011-05-03
3      123213      1       2011-05-03
4      155432      10      2011-05-01
5      155432      10      2011-05-02
```

**Id** is an identity column i added to my table variable (will explain why i need it in a moment). **ProductId** is a **Product**. **Rank** is a value which represents a product's rank at a given time. **RankCreated** is the time that **Product** was ranked.

What im trying to do:

> Calculate the "movement" between each product rank, for each product. Where "movement" is defined as current - previous.

So the "computed column" would look like this:

```
Id     ProductId   Rank    RankCreated   Movement
1      123213      2       2011-05-02    NULL
2      123213      4       2011-05-03    2
3      123213      1       2011-05-03    -3
4      155432      10      2011-05-01    NULL
5      155432      10      2011-05-02    0
```

I added the **Id** column so i could use that to fetch the previous record.

Here's how i got the data into the temp table:

```
insert into @rankhistories (productid, [rank], [rankcreated])
select a.ProductId, b.[rank]
from dbo.ProductRankHistories b
inner join dbo.Products a on a.ProductId = b.ProductId
order by a.ProductId, b.RankCreated
```

I really can't see how i can avoid a cursor here. There are 6000+ records in that table variable, and with my cursor solution it took 5 seconds, which isn't acceptable.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TV TABLE
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ProductId INT,
Rank INT,   
RankCreated DATE
)


 /*Populate *6000 rows of random data*/
INSERT INTO @TV
SELECT TOP 6000 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) / 9 AS ProductId,
              CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 10 AS Rank,
              GETDATE() AS RankCreated
FROM master..spt_values v1,master..spt_values v2


SELECT t1.Id, 
       t1.ProductId, 
       t1.Rank, 
       t1.RankCreated, 
       t2.Rank - t1.Rank AS Movement 
FROM @TV t1
LEFT MERGE JOIN @TV t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id+1 AND t1.ProductId=t2.ProductId
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Comment: clever - but actually takes longer than the cursor - takes 6 seconds. exec plan shows SORT taking 63% of cost.

Comment: @rpm1984 - Did you make the `Id` column the primary key so it has an index on it? (I'm guessing not as I don't see a sort) What does the Join look like in the execution plan? Actually you might get better performance with a `#temp` table than a `@tablevariable` here.

Comment: @Martin - adding the PK had no effect. The SORT was removed from the exec plan, but still 5 seconds. But with a #temp table it's now instant! 0 seconds! You rock - thanks! +1 and accepted

Comment: @RPM1984 - If you add a `LEFT MERGE JOIN` hint to the table variable version that's pretty instant also. There are no stats for table variables so it chooses a nested loops plan left to its own devices.

Comment: @Martin - any idea why using a #temp table makes it faster?

Comment: @Martin - also, i don't think we need the `ORDER BY t1.Id`

Comment: @Martin - sir. you are a fraking legend! I've had to wear a helmet becuase your solution is blowing my mind. A -merge- join? WTF? So kewl!

Comment: @RPM1984 - It doesn't maintain statistics for table variables and always assumes they will contain exactly one row. This can lead to it making bad choices rather than choosing a nested loops join rather than a merge join. I notice though that even when I use the `LEFT MERGE JOIN` hint in the `@tablevariable` version it still chucks an additional sort into the plan though which isn't there in the `#temp` version. Not sure why that is there as the merge join is order preserving anyway.

Comment: @Martin - u said "and always assumes they will contain exactly one row". Can u please elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: @Pure - If you mouse over the arrows coming out of the table variable in the actual execution plan you will see "Estimated Number of Rows =1" vs "Actual Number of Rows = 6000" as a result its estimated costs when evaluating alternative versions of plans is way out. In the `#temp` table version the statement will get recompiled after the insert has happened and it will take account of the actual number of rows.